# Select2 add/update on input change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 element and an input element as follows...

```
Label: <input class="default-ele" type="text"/>
<select class="some-select">
  <option>-- None --</option> 
</select>
```

and some JS/JQuery as follows...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(`.${type}-default`).select2({
    theme: 'bootstrap'
  });

  $(document).on('change', '.default-ele', function() {
    var newVal = $(this).val();
    var selAdd = new Option(newVal, newVal);
    $('.some-select').append(selAdd).trigger('change');
  });

});
```

That all works except that if you enter a value into the input then click the select with the cursor still in the input, the value is not there until you move focus away from the select and back to it. Is there a timeout or some other way to get the value to display when immediately clicking on the select after the input changes?

TIA

Comment: Use the events provided by the plugin and pass them through the options when you initialize your select2 dropdown.  See https://select2.github.io/options.html#events

Comment: why not have a button to add it to dropdown?

Comment: this is dynamic (I trimmed some of the code down for brevity). One goal is usability and minimizing clicks. Also, the select is already initialized at the point the value is input.

Comment: @DDurham add a key press event for key `enter`? after input you press enter and added to the dropdown, also clean the input as well?

Comment: @kyle the change event is being used to populate

Comment: @Daniel H - that assumes the user would know to and actually press enter which cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: The inputs are dynamic (there can and most likely will be more than one). Most users are going to fill the last (or only) one in then immediately click the select to set the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use keypress event to trigger 'select' refresh functionality.

Something like below.

This should update trigger callback on input as soon as you lift key.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(`.${type}-default`).select2({
    theme: 'bootstrap'
  });

  $(document).on('keyup', '.default-ele', function() {
    var newVal = $(this).val();
    var selAdd = new Option(newVal, newVal);
    $('.some-select').append(selAdd).trigger('change');
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks much, this seems to work so I'll accept, and up vote but it does seem like it may impact overall performance and it still seems like the change event should fire BEFORE the select drop down occurs regardless - but apparently it does not ;-(